Using Gilroy font on pdfLateX
I couldn't find the answer to this in the sea of questions of this kind.
I'm trying to implement the font Gilroy-ExtraBold in my overleaf test and I don't know why I'm failing. Here is my attempt (made on overleaf):
\pdfmapline{+gilroy Gilroy-ExtraBold < Gilroy-ExtraBold.ttf <T1-WGL4.enc}

\newcommand\gilroyfont[1]{{\usefont{T1}{gilroy}{m}{n} #1 }}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{firstpage}
\raisebox{2cm}{\hspace{4.5cm}\normalfont\fontsize{25}{30}\bfseries\uppercase{\gilroyfont{Title} } \newline} \raisebox{1cm}{ \hspace*{-11.25cm} \normalfont\fontsize{25}{30}\bfseries\uppercase{First test}}

I just tested and the \normalfont + \fontsize do not matter. My Title is appearing with the default font instead the one I want. Here are my files:

I obtained the ttf file from a website for dowloads of fonts, the tfm file from windows' powershell "ttf2tmf" command on the ttf file and I just copied and changed random fd file to match Gilroy-ExtraBold's one.
I can't see what went wrong.

it would be much easier to use lualatex rather than pdflatex then you could use the ttf file directly without having to make tfm and map files etc

will lualatex change too much the diagramation tho?

you probably need to reencode the font. as far as I've found, you can't use the ttf directly with pdftex. (I don't mean you have to convert it to type1. you can use the ttf as-is, but the map line.)

sorry i do no what you mean but you have not given any information about your document or about your font definitions so all I can say is that in general most pdflatex documents can be easily made to work with lualatex (you can easily test on overleaf, just select luatex in the menu) and in general it is much much easier to use true type and opentype fonts with luatex than pdftex

not sure what you mean by 'diagramation' but lualatex will probably make very little difference, if any, to the typeset output except that you may need to change your font setup.

ok I used LuaLatex on the compilator. How do I code to use gilroy now?

\usepackage{fontspec} \newfontfamily\gilroy{Gilroy-ExtraBold.ttf} ... \begin{document}  {\gilroy hello}

It worked, thanks

It would be easier to use lualatex then directly access the font via
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\gilroy{Gilroy-ExtraBold.ttf}
\begin{document} 
... {\gilroy hello} ..
\end{document}

